# Polygon Representation from Contours

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, contour

I have contours lines along with their elevations in ArcGIS. I want to create a polygon representation from those contour lines. How can i create polygons from those contours which may help me to represent them on my map.

Comment: You'll want to read the answer to this question [link](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61550/colouring-areas-between-vector-contours?lq=1) -- And keep in mind my disfavored answer to this question [link](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60034/how-calculate-areas-between-certain-contour-lines-in-qgis/76906#76906) -- What you want to do is fairly easy but it may not get you the result you need (hence the two links for discussion).

Answer (score 2):

If I'm getting what you want, following two methods could be used via ArcToolbox.

1. Analysis Tool --> Proximity --> Buffer, the buffer will give you a new layer of polygon.
2. Data Management Tool--> Feature --> Feature to polygon